# How to get the virtual path of File from wwwroot folder of asp.net core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, directory, directory-structure

I want to get the virtual path to my index.html file which is present in wwwroot folder of my asp.net core web API. I have attached my picture of code which will explain the situation of this problem.

[image: this is the image of my code please look at this]

right now I am just using its full path which is not convenient method of using path like this so that is why I want to get virtual path of this file so that on any other server I will not face any problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated**

Inject `IWebHostEnvironment` in your controller and use its `WebRootPath` to access your files

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
//...

public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public AccountController(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    //...

    string htmlFilePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "EmailTemplate", "index.html");

    //...
}
```

**Answer for older ASP.NET Core versions**

Inject `IHostingEnvironment` in your controller and use its `WebRootPath` to access your files

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
//...

public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public AccountController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In 2023 instead of `IHostingEnvironment` you will use `IWebHostEnvironment` and inject that like Alexander response.